# Website toggling full screen mode in Chrome, after ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, debugging

I still fighting with one Chrome issue on my webpage. There is pagination, that loads content via ajax call:
https://elody.cz/nase-nevesty

When I click 2nd, 3d, .. tab in pagination. The load is being performed and after that, it jumps into fullscreen mode.

You can also check on this video:
https://www.loom.com/share/768557e080f1471393aa0377d3fec024

I have this issue on Mac as well as on Windows – in Chrome.

Please, do anybody know how to fix that?

Thank you!
Filip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside ba_gallery.js there is following line:

```
    var fullscreen = true;
```

set this value to false may solve your problem, i guess its worth a try

Comment: That would indeed fix the problem. Watch Line: 2071 and 2768-2794

Comment: Thank you so much! I remove all places where was this variable set to true and it resolved the problem! :-)

Answer (score 1):

After ajax is done you could verify if its in fullscreen mode, if yes set its to false.
document.fullscreenEnabled : test id browser supports fullscreen
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen(); turn your page in to fullscreen

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function (event) {
if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    // fullscreen is activated
} else {
    // fullscreen is cancelled
}
});
```

testing if its in full screen

document.exitFullscreen(); getting out

Comment: That would be a very 'hacky' way to fix that issue. I would recommend to find the source of the problem

Comment: Yes, but if none of them work ,you could try it, don`t you like to have multiple options to solve a problem?

Comment: I don't think that solutions that only build around the problem are good solutions. They only worsen the performance and reduce the overview even more. Unfortunately, I am used to such work from my company which leads to many problems. If you rather take time to find the cause of the problem, then you can also remove the unnecessary code and maybe you have gained a bit of overview.